# Trouble With API Curl Response(php)

Tags: php, api, associative-array

I am having trouble with the response from Companies House API. I am making the following curl request from a php page:

```
$request_url_1 ='https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/' ;
$company_number = 11495745;
$request_url_2 = '/officers';
$request_url = $request_url_1 . $company_number . $request_url_2;   
  $ch = curl_init($request_url); 
  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$chkey:")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  $content = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close( $ch ); 
  $contents = json_decode($content,true);
```

The following is the response that is 'pasted' on the php page after sending the curl request, and I cannot seem to get at the contents/value of the $contents variable that should contain the curl response.

```
 {
   "active_count":1,
   "items_per_page":35,
   "kind":"officer-list",
   "etag":"6cc48213158205c9fa85492a4c2ef0a98b56b2f1",
   "resigned_count":2,
   "items":[
      {
         "date_of_birth":{
            "year":1963,
            "month":2
         },
         "appointed_on":"2019-08-01",
         "nationality":"British",
         "address":{
            "address_line_1":"Moorside Crescent",
            "country":"United Kingdom",
            "address_line_2":"Sinfin",
            "postal_code":"DE24 9PH",
            "locality":"Derby",
            "premises":"75"
         },
         "occupation":"Company Director",
         "links":{
            "officer":{
               "appointments":"/officers/IryiaaBZodlGNaOP0Rf3Pb2GnO8/appointments"
            }
         },
         "name":"MILLER, Eira",
         "country_of_residence":"England",
         "officer_role":"director"
      },
      {
         "date_of_birth":{
            "month":3,
            "year":1987
         },
         "nationality":"English",
         "occupation":"Company Director",
         "address":{
            "locality":"Derby",
            "address_line_1":"Moorside Crescent",
            "premises":"75",
            "country":"United Kingdom",
            "postal_code":"DE24 9PH",
            "address_line_2":"Sinfin"
         },
         "appointed_on":"2018-12-10",
         "resigned_on":"2019-07-31",
         "name":"KING, Kimberley Rachel",
         "links":{
            "officer":{
               "appointments":"/officers/av7G3-iF_9-FXhRH2xm-IxejeGQ/appointments"
            }
         },
         "country_of_residence":"United Kingdom",
         "officer_role":"director"
      },
      {
         "address":{
            "postal_code":"DE24 9PH",
            "locality":"Derby",
            "country":"United Kingdom",
            "premises":"75",
            "address_line_2":"Sinfin",
            "address_line_1":"Moorside Crescent"
         },
         "occupation":"Managing Director",
         "nationality":"British",
         "appointed_on":"2018-08-01",
         "resigned_on":"2018-12-10",
         "officer_role":"director",
         "country_of_residence":"United Kingdom",
         "links":{
            "officer":{
               "appointments":"/officers/X9nlVD6qIIENMjaH946__4CB3QE/appointments"
            }
         },
         "name":"MARTIN, Katey",
         "date_of_birth":{
            "month":6,
            "year":1968
         }
      }
   ],
   "links":{
      "self":"/company/11495745/officers"
   },
   "inactive_count":0,
   "start_index":0,
   "total_results":3
}
```

I have tried returning result as non-associative array and access it through normal array but no joy there either.

FluffyKitten kindly supplied the following code to perform the extraction of the name field:

```
$item = $contents["items"];
foreach($item as $items){
    echo $items["name"];
}
```

However, this couldn't access the required  data. A print_r of $contents results in '1' and a var_dump (1)

Comment: The sample data you posted is not valid, parseable JSON.

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Comment: also, the second param for json_decode being true makes it return an array, but you're trying to access properties as an object in your loop. assuming you have some valid json somewhere, try removing the second param, or else access the data properly.

Comment: Just replaced the json curl response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problem with your code:

1. You are mixing up code for accessing arrays and objects
2. You are looping when there is no need for loops

You are using `json_decode($content,true)`, and by passing in that `true` parameter, you are converting the result into associative arrays, but then you try to access `items` as the property of an object.

Because you have converted the contents to an associative array, you can easily access the information you want using the correct keys, e.g.:

```
$item = $contents["items"];
foreach($item as $items){
    echo "<p>".$items["name"];
}
```

**Reference** [PHP `json_decode` Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**UPDATE**:

Your question has changed totally - it was about how to loop through the variable with the results, but now it seems that the problem is saving the results as a variable in the first place.

You need to set the [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to `true` so that the result is not output directly (I assume this is what you mean by the result being "pasted" into the PHP page).

Add this to your CURL code, and *if the rest of your code is correct*, the result should be saved in the `$content` variable so you can use it to loop through using the code above:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, didn't help though - the api response is 'pasting' the data on to the the php page I am making the url request from, and I can't seem to get at the contents of  '$contents' variable.

Comment: @Nick I don't understand what you mean by it is "pasting" the data onto the php page? Also, you create the `$contents` variable yourself - do you mean the problem is with the `$content` variable? This looks like a different problem then what you actually asked in your question, which was about looping through the array, so please edit your question with details of the actual problem and the related code, e.g. the code you use to call the API, save the JSON into the `$content` variable, etc.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer - this should work, but it's difficult to tell when we don't have access you the API and also when you are referencing variables (e.g. `$chkey`) that you don't mention anywhere else

Comment: thankyou so much for your patience and expertise. Yes the header change worked as did your JSON parsing.  Initially I was doing a print_r of the CURL return so didn't realise that the header was causing the return to be printed on the page. It was only after taking the print_r out and the JSON return was still being printed that I realised the problem wasn't the JSON parsing! ($chkey = private API credentials). Again, FluffyKitten thankyou very much for your assistance